# Removing 'checked' attribute does not change its display in the browser

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button group where each button should light up when it's "checked".  It half works which is to say it doesn't work (only one button should be active at any time).

[image]

```
 let stanceBar = ["long", "short", "out", "none"]
            .map(
                (stanceElement) =>
                    `
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    class="btn-check"
                    id="${stanceElement}"
                    autoComplete="off"
                    readOnly
                />
                <label
                    class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm"
                    for="${stanceElement}"
                >
                    ${stanceElement}
                </label>
                `
            )
            .join("")

<<This is inserted into a div>>
```

listeners:

```
        document.getElementById(stance).addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            let target = e.target as HTMLInputElement
            s.stance = target.id
            setState['s](s) // Run my setter script to kick off the for loop below
        })
    })
```

part of "setter" script

```
            for (const stance of ["long", "short", "out", "none"]) {
                const element = document.getElementById(stance)
                // console.log(s.stance, "=", stance, s.stance === stance)
                if (s.stance === stance) {
                    console.log("setting", stance, "button to", s.stance === stance)
                    element.setAttribute("checked", "")
                } else {
                    console.log("setting", stance, "button to", s.stance === stance)
                    element.removeAttribute("checked")
                }
            }
```

When I click the buttons, I do get the button I click to activate, but the other buttons that were previously active don't deactivate. I have debugged line by line and the removeAttribute statement is apparently running.  Just nothing happens.  If I run the same statement from the browser console it works fine.

```js
let stanceBar = ["long", "short", "out", "none"]
  .map(
    (stanceElement) =>
    `
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    class="btn-check"
                    id="${stanceElement}"
                    autoComplete="off"
                    readOnly
                />
                <label
                    class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm"
                    for="${stanceElement}"
                >
                    ${stanceElement}
                </label>
                `
  )
  .join("")
document.getElementById('stanceBar').innerHTML = stanceBar

;
let s = {
  stance: 'none'
};
["long", "short", "out", "none"].forEach((stance) => {
  document.getElementById(stance).addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    let target = e.target
    s.stance = target.id
    setter() // setState["s"](s)
  })
})

function setter() {
  for (const stance of ["long", "short", "out", "none"]) {
    const element = document.getElementById(stance)
    if (s.stance === stance) {
      element.setAttribute("checked", "")
    } else {
      element.removeAttribute("checked")
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='stanceBar'></div>
```

Comment: `checked` is a property, `element.checked = true;` and `element.checked = false;` instead of calling `setAttribute()` and `removeAttribute()` respectively - or even better, you can remove the entire `if` statement with `element.checked = s.stance !== stance;`

Comment: @Rory: I'm using vanilla JS and html.  Trying to use checked as a property does not work. Maybe what you're describing is a React thing? That's in fact the first thing I tried and ended up having to do it the more messy way I have above.

Comment: There is no name attribute so the radio buttons are not linked.

Comment: snippet added.  @epascarello, in React this worked fine just by setting the active attribute on each of the buttons.  Even now if I manually add the removeAttribute it will have the desired effect.  I just dont' understand why it's not working from my script.

Comment: @epascarello, looks like you were right.  I don't understand why it's needed since I have IDs for each, but whatever works.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a name attribute when mapping the radio buttons  `name="stance"`

it basically acts as container & everytime you change the radio element it is overwritten as it can only have one value at a time

```js
let stanceBar = ["long", "short", "out", "none"]
  .map(
    (stanceElement) =>
    `
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    class="btn-check"
                    id="${stanceElement}"
                    autoComplete="off"
                    name="stance"
                    readOnly
                />
                <label
                    class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm"
                    for="${stanceElement}"
                >
                    ${stanceElement}
                </label>
                `
  )
  .join("")
document.getElementById('stanceBar').innerHTML = stanceBar

;
let s = {
  stance: 'none'
};
["long", "short", "out", "none"].forEach((stance) => {
  document.getElementById(stance).addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    let target = e.target
    s.stance = target.id
    setter() // setState["s"](s)
  })
})

function setter() {
  for (const stance of ["long", "short", "out", "none"]) {
    const element = document.getElementById(stance)
    if (s.stance === stance) {
      element.setAttribute("checked", "")
    } else {
      element.removeAttribute("checked")
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='stanceBar'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you!  I have no idea why just adding any name to each of those buttons works but it did.  I had a unique ID assigned to each one but never imagined I'd need 'name'.

Answer (score 0):

If you supply your radio buttons with a shared `name` attribute (radio button group), the selection will only be applied to one at a time.

```js
const defaultOptions = ['long', 'short', 'out', 'none'];

const renderStanceBar = (name, options = defaultOptions) => 
  options.map(
    (option) => `
      <input
        type="radio"
        class="btn-check"
        name="${name}"
        id="${option}"
        autoComplete="off"
      />
      <label
        class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm"
        for="${option}"
      >
        ${option}
      </label>
    `).join('');

document.querySelectorAll('.stance-bar')
  .forEach(stanceBar =>
    stanceBar.innerHTML = renderStanceBar('stance'));
```

```css
:root {
  --background-color: #212529;
  --primary-color: #0D6EFD;
  --secondary-color: #FFF;
}

* { margin: 0; user-select: none; }
*, *::before, *::after { box-sizing: border-box; }
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
body { display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; background: var(--background-color); font-family: Arial; }

.stance-bar {
  display: flex;
  border: thin solid var(--primary-color);
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  color: var(--primary-color);
}

.stance-bar label {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0.667rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.stance-bar label {
  border-right: thin solid var(--primary-color);
}

.stance-bar label:first-of-type {
  border-top-left-radius: 0.4rem;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0.4rem;
}

.stance-bar label:last-of-type {
  border-right: none;
  border-top-right-radius: 0.4rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0.4rem;
}

.stance-bar input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background: var(--primary-color);
  color: var(--secondary-color);
}

.stance-bar input[type="radio"] {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
};
```

```html
<div class="stance-bar"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `setter()` function is redundant and unnecessary. Browsers have built-in ability to ensure that only one radio in a group (defined by use of the `name` attribute) is checked at a time.

The only time you would need to worry about checking them using the code is if you were starting off with none checked and wanted to check a specific one, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Even so, the way to check a radio that has already been rendered is to set its `.checked` property, *not* to change its attributes. And you would only need to check one of them in that case, not iterate through all of them.

Simplified, working code:

```js
let stanceBar = ["long", "short", "out", "none"]
  .map(
    (stanceElement) =>
    `
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    name="stance"
                    class="btn-check"
                    id="${stanceElement}"
                    autoComplete="off"
                    readOnly
                />
                <label
                    class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm"
                    for="${stanceElement}"
                >
                    ${stanceElement}
                </label>
                `
  )
  .join("")
document.getElementById('stanceBar').innerHTML = stanceBar;
let s = {
  stance: 'none'
};

["long", "short", "out", "none"].forEach((stance) => {
  document.getElementById(stance).addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    let target = e.target
    s.stance = target.id;
    
    console.log(s.stance);
  })
});
```

```html
<div id='stanceBar'></div>
```

Comment: I have a setter function for setting state across my full application.  This way if I set state on a variable I can have specific instructions for all updates to the DOM needed that depend on that variable.  I understand your point though that in this case it's superfluous.

Comment: @BaronYoung In that case, this would suffice for updating the radio buttons' DOM to match the state: `function setter() { const el = document.getElementById(s.stance); if (el) { el.checked = true; } }`

Comment: Interesting...I'll have to try that.  Thanks.